# Get next month using mktime()

Tags: php, date, mktime

I'm trying to get the next month using PHP `mktime()` function.

I am looking to get a result like `07/2015` but instead it is giving me `01/2015`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$next_month = strftime('%d/%Y', strtotime('+1 month', mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)));
```

The value of `$month` is 06.

The value of `$year` is 2015.

Comment: Of course you're getting `01/2015`. You're printing the day of the month after you've specifically set this to `1`. I suspect you want `strftime('%m/%Y', ...);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using your version, then it should be `%m` instead of `%d`, i.e.:

```
$year = 2015;
$month = 6;
echo strftime('%m/%Y', strtotime('+1 month', mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about giving [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) a try. For example:

```
$date = new DateTime('next month');
echo $date->format('m/Y');
```

If the month and year are variable, then the following would also work:

```
$date = new DateTime("$year-$month-01");
$date->modify('next month');
echo $date->format('m/Y');
```

Comment: How would I use that with an input of 06/2015?  I basically need to add 1 month onto 06/2015.

Comment: Updated with variable input.